# How to convert JSON object into date format?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json

This is my JSON

```
{
    0 = "2011-11-11";
    1 = "2011-12-31";
    endDate = "2011-12-31";
    startDate = "2011-11-11";
}
```

My code is

```
NSString *dateString = [jsonDict  objectForKey:@"0"]

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"EE, d LLLL yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString]; 
[dateFormat release];
```

But this code is not working.

How do I convert JSON data into date format?

Comment: in which format you need date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong format in `setDateFormat`. You should be using:

```
NSString *dateString = [jsonDict  objectForKey:@"0"]

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString]; 
[dateFormat release];
```

Comment: Also, if you're using it repeatedly, you should declare your NSDateFormatter static and lazy-create it (if date format == nil etc), as it's pretty expensive to create. Great performance gains.